# TYPO3 9 LTS - Routing breaks extbase action-links

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

What do i need to configure to avoid *typo3* losing the query string once a url has been resolved as a route?

I have this generated URL:

```
http://host.local:8000/{LANG}/{PATH}/{TO}/{PAGE}?plugin_namespace[action]=list&plugin_namespace[controller]=ControllerName&plugin_namespace[page]=2&cHash=1147d04e517568fa0bc4c9c121bc5f35
```

So i am fine with the cHash in this case (no cHash would be nicer but funk it) but my problem is, that *TYPO3* des not realize the action parameter. When Debugging the request object in the controller i see, that the request has not been mapped correctly to the plugin.

The request object contains the full request URI with all params and so on but i am not able to generate a subrequest to that plugin...

Can i set up the default behaviour of *typo3* to simply interprate the umapped query part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my nginx directive

not working:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
}
```

working

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```